# wrong console module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have downloaded a [python script](https://gist.github.com/omz/6108848) that imports `console` module. This module was not found in my system so I installed it using `pip`. When the script tries to access functions `console.login_alert` and `console.input_alert` the following error is raised: *'module' object has no attribute 'input_alert'*

I suppose I am using a wrong `console`module but I do not know how to install the correct one. I am using python 2.7 and this is the information about the module I installed using pip.

```
>pip install console
Collecting console
  Downloading console-0.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: console
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for console ... done

Successfully built console
Installing collected packages: console
Successfully installed console-0.1.1
```

Comment: Show us your code to work with the module

Comment: Did you name your script `console.py`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andrey Taptunov. I've added the link to the script in my question.

Comment: @WoLy No, I did not name the script `console.py`.  The script is named `iTC Downloader.py`and it can be downloaded from https://gist.github.com/omz/6108848

Comment: As I know `console.login_alert()` is available for IOS, Check http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/console.html